# mockito - how to check an instance inside a method

Tags: java, mockito, matcher, argument-matcher

I am new to Mockito, I am trying to verify the attributes of an object which gets created inside a method.

pseudo code below:

```
class A{
   ...    
   public String methodToTest(){
       Parameter params = new Parameter(); //param is basically like a hashmap
       params.add("action", "submit");
       return process(params);
   }
   ...
   public String process(Parameter params){
       //do some work based on params 
       return "done";  
   }
}
```

I want to test 2 things:

1. when I called `methodToTest`, `process()` method is called
2. `process()` method is called with the correct params containing action `"submit"`

I was able to verify that `process()` is eventually called easily using `Mockito.verify()`.
However trying to check that params contains action `"submit"` is very difficult so far.

I have tried the following but it doesn't work :(

```
BaseMatcher<Parameter> paramIsCorrect = new BaseMatcher<Parameter>(){
    @Overrides
    public boolean matches(Object param){
        return ("submit".equals((Parameter)param.get("action")));
    }

    //@Overrides description but do nothing
}

A mockA = mock(A);
A realA = new A();
realA.methodToTest();
verify(mockA).process(argThat(paramIsCorrect))
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have got verify() to work, presumably it is just a case of using an argument matcher to check the contains of params.

http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#3

The example given in the above docs is `verify(mockedList).get(anyInt())`.  You can also say `verify(mockedList).get(argThat(myCustomMatcher))`.

As an aside, it sounds like you are mocking the class under test.  I've found that this usually means I haven't thought clearly about either my class or my test or both.  In your example, you should be able to test that `methodToTest()` returns the right result irrespective of whether or not it calls `process()` because it returns a `String`.  The mockito folk have lots of good documentation about this sort thing, particularly the "monkey island" blog: http://monkeyisland.pl/.

Comment: Hi fbarber I actually tried argThat() but I was getting all kinds of errors and I tried so many things but never check my own matches implementation... as it turns out I had some stupid error in my basematcher >.<

Answer (score 0):

Just pass `Parameter` in as a constructor argument to a constructor of the class `A`, then use a mocked instance/implementation of `Parameter` in your test and verify on the mock. That is how it is normally done - you separate your classes and compose them using *constructor injection*, that enables you to pass in mocks for testing purposes (it also allows rewiring the application and exchanging some commons a lot easier).

If you need to create `Parameter` on every function invocation you should use a factory that creates `Parameter` instances and pass that in. Then you can verify on the factory as well as the object created by the factory.